# Navigations breaks by zooming

Tags: html, css, navigation, zooming

I already found some threads with the same problem that I have, but they didn't help me. When ever I zoom in on 25%, my last navigation-button breaks on the next line.

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="menu">
    <nav>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>

    body
{
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
}

li
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #00514C;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    width: 160.8px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-right: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

li a
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 
}

li:hover
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

li:last-child
{   
    border-right: none;
}

ul
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

#menu 
{
    position: relative;
    width: 975px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a rounding/ratio problem when you zoom in and out. ( 25% )

1. When you zoom in or out, you will encounter issues because of
   rounding and text rendering. It is a good idea to make sure the
   layout can survive a bit of stretching without breaking down.
2. Relative positioning is affected by issues mentioned in #1, and
   therefore unreliable.
3. Look into using something to remove the properties that the various
   browsers will apply. You could use a reset to give you something
   more workable or try to normalize the values to make them more even
   between browsers.

By Changing lines below in your CSS file (li, ul) will solve the problem in Firefox, Chrome, etc.
Change width: 135px and Add margin: 2px

```
li
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #00514C;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    width: 135px;  
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-right: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Smaller in Chrome (ul width set to 822px in css)

```
ul
{
    width: 822;
    margin-left: -40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using divs with display: table and display: table-cell.

```
<div id="menu">
<nav>
   <div class="box">
      <div><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Link 4</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Link 5</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Link 6</a></div>
   </div>
</nav>
</div>

body
{
background-color: #000000;
margin: 0;
}

.box div
{
display: table-cell;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #00514C;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: "Calibri";
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
border-right: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

a
{
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
line-height: 
}

.box div:hover
{
background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.box div:last-child
{   
border-right: none;
}

.box
{
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

#menu 
{
position: relative;
width: 975px;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TC4p7/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I used "display: block", to achieve, that it's possible to click the navigation everywhere. Withouth that, I have to click exactly on link.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I did not change display: block; on 'a' tag, you can still do that, if you don't want it just remove display: block; or change it to display: inline-block;. I am not sure if that is what you are asking.